# Override audit field @CreatedDate

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

How to over ride audit field having `@CreatedDate`. if value is not set for audit field `@CreatedDate` should be applied other wise it should take the value that has been set. Is there any feature to enable in spring JPA.

Answer (score 4):

It's not elegant, but if you want to reset the value of the `@CreatedDate` field, you can save the entity after the initial save with any date you like:

```
  // creates entity
  repository.save(entity);

  // overwrite created date on the entity
  entity.setCreatedDate(getSomeCreatedDate());

  // re-save the entity
  repository.save(entity);
```

Comment: It works for `@CreatedDate`, but it doesn't for `@LastModifiedDate`.